# Cannot import requests after using 'pip3 install requests'

Tags: python

I am trying to import 'requests' in my python code(Python 3.5.2). I did the following:

1. first downloaded get-pip.py, and install it using python shell
2. then in my cmd directory for scripts: `C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts>, I typed "pip3 install requests"`. I got no error message for this step, and no message telling me the installation is successful either.

However, when run my python code, still got error `File "C:/pycode/dl_proxy3.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'`

Can't figure out what's the problem. Why the requests module still not installed.

Comment: Why did you think you needed `get-pip`? pip comes with Python3

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I just used 'easy_install-3.5 pip', then 'pip3 install requests'. The import is successful.

Comment: Again... `pip` is **pre-installed** with Python 3, so you don't need to install it yourself.

Comment: ok, i see. Thanks so much for the clarification.